# Which one is better for writing automated test cases, Behat-Mink Bundle or Sahi Recorder?

Tags: testing, automated-tests, behat, sahi, mink

At present i am using Behat-Mink Bundle for performing **automation testing via sahi**.
The other way to do Automation Testing is recording Test Cases using Sahi Recorder.
So which method is ***better***, Using **Sahi Recorder or Behat-Mink Bundle**?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: You need to define what your criteria is for "better".